# wp_set_object_terms() custom taxonomy not working correctly when using insert post

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, wp-insert-post

I'm using `wp_set_object_terms($postId, Array('tag1','tag2','tag3'), 'customtaxonomy');`
with `wp_insert_post` to automatically create a new post.
it will show as

[image]

But on wordpress editor it is separated not like combined together as the image above, what I do to fix this is I only need to manually published or click the update button of editor to make them separated

[image]

I'm not really sure why it is acting like this?

Comment: This would just be how your theme displays tags. You would need to ask the author why, or the best way to change it

Comment: on my custom taxonomy list it store as tag1, tag2, tag3
it will really separated if I click the Update button or Published saving it first to draft :(

Comment: anyway i'll try to ask the theme creator, Thanks